# Move MailItem to specified folder

Tags: vba, outlook

Can someone help me with this small script I am trying to implement in VBA?

What appends is that the loop randomly stops and I can not move all the mail in "archivio" folder.

```
Private Sub aggiorna_click()

    Dim x As Object
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim itm, sgsa, actionPlan, cartella, specCartella As Object
    Dim olDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set itm = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set sgsa = itm.Folders("SGSA")
    Set actionPlan = sgsa.Folders("action plan")
    Set cartella = actionPlan.Folders(tipo.Text)
    Set specCartella = cartella.Folders(piano.Text)

Set olDestFolder = itm.Folders("archivio")
For Each x In specCartella.Items
    x.Move olDestFolder
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: any error?? if so, which number??

Comment: no error. The loop just end

Comment: did it move anything?? any single item??

Comment: it moves just some mails, usually not more than 4 .

Comment: when you move (or delete items) your loop should start with last element and move toward 1st... so, you need to change your loop into something like this: `For i=specCartella.Items.Count To 1 Step -1`... Will you figure it out on your own further??

Comment: ... and it works!!!! do you know the reason of that ? why does my method was wrong? and, of course, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: there are no special explanation... imagine you have stack of books, 1st at the bottom, last at the top... after you remove 1st one you change the order- 2nd becomes 1st... Loop can't efficiently solve that new order... Thanks for the answer acceptance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to comments under the question, the new loop could look like this one **(not tested)**

```
Dim i As Long
For i = specCartella.Items.Count to 1 Step -1
    specCartella.Items(i).Move olDestFolder
Next i
```

(i have just changed x with i!)